# Calculate the running standard deviation

Tags: c++, statistics

I am converting equations to c++. Is this correct for a running standard deviation.

```
this->runningStandardDeviation = (this->sumOfProcessedSquaredSamples - sumSquaredDividedBySampleCount) / (sampleCount - 1);
```

Here is the full function:

```
void BM_Functions::standardDeviationForRunningSamples (float samples [], int sampleCount)
{
    // update the running process samples count
    this->totalSamplesProcessed += sampleCount;

    // get the mean of the samples
    double mean = meanForSamples(samples, sampleCount);

    // sum the deviations
   // sum the squared deviations
   for (int i = 0; i < sampleCount; i++)
   {
        // update the deviation sum of processed samples
        double deviation = samples[i] - mean;
        this->sumOfProcessedSamples += deviation;

        // update the squared deviations sum
        double deviationSquared = deviation * deviation;
        this->sumOfProcessedSquaredSamples += deviationSquared;
    }

    // get the sum squared
    double sumSquared = this->sumOfProcessedSamples * this->sumOfProcessedSamples;

    // get the sum/N
    double sumSquaredDividedBySampleCount = sumSquared / this->totalSamplesProcessed;

    this->runningStandardDeviation = sqrt((this->sumOfProcessedSquaredSamples -     sumSquaredDividedBySampleCount) / (sampleCount - 1));
}
```

Comment: `sumOfProcessedSquaredSamples - sumSquaredDividedBySampleCount` looks suspicious, could you add some comments to show what you want to achieve and what does each variable mean? thx.

Comment: also, shouldn't there be a square root somewhere?

Comment: Thanks, missed the square root. Why does the equation show σ * σ = ... rather than σ = sqrt(....) ?

Comment: σ * σ is the variance or so and easier to write than a sqrt symbol.

Comment: sumSquaredDividedBySampleCount = the deviations summed and then squared. With that divided by the sample count.

Answer (score 13):

A numerically stable and efficient algorithm for computing the running mean and variance/SD is [Welford's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Welford's_Online_algorithm).

One C++ implementation would be:

```
std::pair<double,double> getMeanVariance(const std::vector<double>& vec) {
    double mean = 0, M2 = 0, variance = 0;

    size_t n = vec.size();
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        double delta = vec[i] - mean;
        mean += delta / (i + 1);
        M2 += delta * (vec[i] - mean);
        variance = M2 / (i + 1);
        if (i >= 2) {
            // <-- You can use the running mean and variance here 
        }
    }

    return std::make_pair(mean, variance);
}
```

Note: to get the SD, just take `sqrt(variance)`

Comment: I have added my implementation if you could take a look please. I "officially" started with c++ yesterday, so excuse any mistakes.

Comment: I'd vote for changing "stable" to "much more stable". And with those floating point divisions, i wouldn't be so sure about the efficiency...

Comment: Efficient as in running in one pass, not tuned to perfection (which would make it hard to get the algorithm across). If you know a way to compute the mean or variance without division I would love to hear about it.

Comment: The variance of 1 to 5 with this method has become 6.04165. Do I miss something. The variance has not defined!

Comment: Fixed a fencepost bug in the code and made it compile. Thanks, user1436187, for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

You may check for sufficient sampleSount (1 would cause division by zero)

MAke sure that the variables have suitable data type (floating point)

Otherwise this looks correct...

Comment: Regarding the data type. I am using doubles in all of these equations. Is this inefficient? I will be done with this library in some time, so computers will only be more powerful. Future proofing? I think if any audio programmer passes 1 on purpose, it should crash, and if its a side effect, crashing could highlight the issue.